# Can someone explain why this vector erase operation isn't working properly?

Tags: c++, vector, erase

```
    vector<int> nums{1,2,3,0,0,0};
    
    for(int i = 0; i< nums.size(); i++){
        if(nums[i] == 0){
            nums.erase(nums.begin() + i);
        }
    }
    for(int i = 0; i< nums.size(); i++){
        cout << nums[i] << " ";
    }
    //I keep getting [1, 2, 3, 0]
```

I want to remove the zeros from the vector so that I only have 1,2,3 left over. However, the method I'm using seems to keep leaving one zero at the end. I've been at it for a while and I've played with the indexing but I can't seem to get it to work correctly. I'd appreciate help thanks.

Comment: When you erase a number, you skip values. Use an iterator loop instead, and pay attention to what `erase` *returns*.

Comment: Look up erase-remove idiom.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every time you erase from a vector the index of following elements decreases by 1. You need to account for this:

```
for(int i = 0; i< nums.size(); i++){
        if(nums[i] == 0){
            nums.erase(nums.begin() + i);
            --i; // <-- HERE
        }
    }
```

This is an `O(n^2)` operation. You can do this in `O(n)` like this:

```
nums.erase(std::remove(nums.begin(), nums.end(), 0),
           nums.end());
```

Comment: --i should be inside if.

Comment: The loop is still O(n), not O(n2)

Comment: @Eugene `std::vector::erase` is `O(n)` because it shifts all trailing elements to the left.

Answer (score 0):

The `vector` `erase` function reduces the size of the vector. The last zero is not getting erased because you are erasing from the same `vector` whose size is getting checked in the `for` loop.

Comment: `nums.erase(nums.begin() + (i--));` will work as it will cancel out the increment and check the same index again.

Comment: Thanks. I was doing an algorithm problem. I ended up doing it in javascript. Was taking too much time to do in C++.

Answer (score 0):

Erase-Remove has been covered, so here's another, but inferior, [X-Y Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). It's worth mentioning because it shows how to use `erase`'s return value.

Use iterators.

```cpp
vector<int> nums{1,2,3,0,0,0};

for(auto it = nums.begin(); it != nums.end(); ){
    if(*it == 0){
        it = nums.erase(it); // erase returns an iterator to the next element
                             // effectively it++ with the added benefit of it
                             // not being invalidated by removal from the vector
    }
    else {
        it++; // not removed? now we need to increment
    }
}
for(const auto & val: nums){
    cout << val << " ";
}
```